# Text Box(Asp.net) value with 3 decimal places handle by Javascript - Regex

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex

I have a asp.net Textbox control which is tagged to accept amount values. It should not accept any value more than 3 decimal places.

123.1 - True

123.12 - True

123.123- True

123.1234 or 12.1234 - False

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server" Width="500px" Visible="false" onkeypress="return isNumber(this,event)"/>
```

Javascript code below.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>         function isNumber(txt, evt) {
>             var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
>
>             if (charCode == 46) {
>                 //Check if the text already contains the . character
>                 if (txt.value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 else {
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>             else {
>                 if (charCode > 31
>              && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
>
>                     return false;
>             }
>
>             return true;
>
>         }
>  </script>
> ```

The JS will validate numerics and .(dot) to be only once. I've tried various combinations of regex which fails. Needs a regex to be handled in JS functions appropriately.
Among the various regex I've applied, here are few "\d+(.\d{1,3})?$", "/^\d+(.\d{1,3})?$/"...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to test with a regular expression that should work in Javascript:

```
var isValidNumber = /^\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$/.test(txt.value);
```

Comment: I've used this same regex before posting .But inside JS, I was not able to execute successfully with if-else loop.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to make the validation. I don't know exactly how you do it (your code example does not use a regular expression).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  best and crisp answer which will validate all conditions

- No multiple dot can be accepted(example:......)
- Accepts only integer
- 3 precised decimal valued

  ```
      function isNumber(txt, evt) {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          var value = txt.value + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
          if (/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?$/.test(value)) {
              return true;
          }
              return false;
      }

  </script>
  ```

Comment: The only difference that I see between your regex and mine is that the one I suggested doesn't allow the value to end with a dot (without decimals).

Comment: Not only that, decimals is maincriteria, in addition this also validates no text entered and no multiple dot's. Also while trying to expedite this, there were instances that numbers once entered cannot be deleted(keyup). All this has been considered and this would suit for all kinds of amount validation by just altering the regex.